# Rewriting url in htaccess not quite sure how to do it

Tags: .htaccess, generics, url-rewriting

Hey guys i'm trying to convert url which looks like this

example.com/sometype/author-name/sort-date
or
example.com/sometype/author-name/sort-date/something-value/

Just need a generic solution.

I'm pretty new to this and a little weak at regular expressions.
So what i could write was this to identify

sometype/author-name/sort-date/

or

sometype/author-name/sort-date/something-value/

/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/ ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)

I want to rewrite this into this format

example.come?data={"par1":"sometype","author":"name","sort":"date","something":"vale"}

or

example.come?data={"par1":"sometype","author":"name","sort":"date"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First understand what you're asking is very unusual and extremely tricky for mod_rewrite. Not only it required recursion based code but also this code won't be very readable.

With that cautionary note enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*?)/?$ $1\",\"$2$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^,]+)(.*)$ $1\":\"$2$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?data={\"part1\":\"$1\"} [L]
```

Comment: Okay i think ill resort to convert www.example.com/something/data1/data2/data3 to www.example.com/anything.php?main=something&&data=data1/data2/data3

For which this is what i've written but it doesnt seem to be working.
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine


RewriteRule     /([^/]*)/?(.*)$ /anything.php?api=$1&&data=$2    [NC,L]

Comment: Wow after spending an hour to come up with above answer you decided to totally change the original problem. Please test out the answer I provided here first. If you want to complete change the problem please post a separate question and I will try to answer that as well.

Comment: Sorry about that Anubhava, ill definitely try testing it. Thanks for so much help!